# Undefined index in collected array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have an array stored in my Laravel cache, which looks like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1058
     all: [
       [
         "name" => "The National",
         "plays" => "7",
         "key" => "the-national",
         "image_paths" => [
           "small" => [
             "path" => "music/artists/the-national",
             "fn" => "170-ea644e846aab551777d3a1ca9b49bdb6.webp",
           ],
           "medium" => [
             "path" => "music/artists/the-national",
             "fn" => "300-ea644e846aab551777d3a1ca9b49bdb6.webp",
           ],
           "large" => [
             "path" => "music/artists/the-national",
             "fn" => "770-ea644e846aab551777d3a1ca9b49bdb6.webp",
           ],
         ],
       ],
       // ...
    ]
}
```

When I retrieve it and `collect` it, I can get the path of the medium image:

```
$artists = collect(Cache::get('recentArtists'));
echo $artists[0]['image_paths']['medium']['path'];
```

But when I try to reference it in blade:

```
{{ $artist['image_paths']['small']['path'] }}
```

I get *Undefined index: medium*.

I've also tried mapping the collection in my controller, but with the same error:

```
$artists->map(function($item, $key) {
    return [
        'name' => $item['name'],
        'img' => $item['image_paths']['medium'],
    ];
});

// Undefined index: medium
```

If I try to return the `array_keys` in the `map`, I get them as expected:

```
=> [
    "tiny",
    "small",
    "medium",
    "large",
],
```

Comment: Are you not missing a ```[0]``` in blade?

Comment: No - the blade statement is in a loop, plus it's giving me the error in the controller if I use `map`

Comment: It is a collection, perhaps the index`['medium']` is present in the first element `[0]`, but not in any of those that follow. Try something like this `$artists->map(function($item, $key) { if( !array_key_exists('medium', $item['image_paths']) ) return $item;
});`

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself well, just for debugging purposes, to get the possible items in which the index is not present.

Comment: I think this was some kind of cache corruption - I found that all the image_path keys were appended to the first element, then when I re-ran the job that populates the cache, it resolved. Thanks for your help